# how to make the page/domain not load the folder where page is located. In ASP.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to make a website, but to make a better control for the pages I want to put them in other folders. lets say this is the link of my profile from stackoverflow

> https://stackoverflow.com/users/6682220/altjen-b

as you can see, it shows the sub-folders it is in. for example users.
I want for the user when he goes to his profile it wont show the users/6682220/userName
but

> stackoverflow.com/userName

even though the userName is inside some other folders.

if this was confusing for you to understand, this is an other example.

this is how I have put the pages.

[image]

but since a lot of pages will be in, it will be hard and confusing to work. so I want to put the Test and Test2 in a specific folder.

at first the link will look like this:
[image]

but after adding inside the folder:
[image]

and this is how it looks in the link in the page.
[image]

so, what can I add/remove or change to make the link from the 4th pic to look like the one in the 2nd pic. But still to be in inside a folder.

I know this is kinda confusing to understand so if there's something you don't understand please tell me for a better explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You talking about asp.net routing feature

Check out msdn docs for it

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd329551.aspx

In `Global.asax` add link to routing namespace

```
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Web.Routing" %>
```

and then edit your Global.asax.cs

```
public class Global : HttpApplication
{

    void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      // Code that runs on application startup
      RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
      BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);

      // Initialize the product database.
      Database.SetInitializer(new ProductDatabaseInitializer());


      // Add Routes.
      RegisterCustomRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
    }

    void RegisterCustomRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
      routes.MapPageRoute(
          "MyRoute",
          "MyApp/{param}",
          "~/RandomFolder/Test.aspx"
      );
    }
}
```